Manga in which the main character is nearly killed by his half-siblings then sent to the place where the dead mythical heroes are
I'm looking for a manga that I read until the most recent chapters were up, then left the manga for a while. Now I can't remember the name of it. Some details I can remember are:

The main character (MC) is male.

The MC is part of a noble family (maybe a falling noble family or the royal family).

The MC is nearly killed by his half-siblings because their mother told them to or something.

After nearly dying, he is sent to the place where the dead mythical heroes are. Some examples are Heracles. I don't remember their names but I do know their titles. The one is the first person to form a contract with four spirit kings and the other one is known as the best archer (even the elves say this). These heroes train him before sending him back to his world.



Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Is this The Max Level Hero Strikes Back...?

Struck by an enemy’s arrow, the powerless Prince Davey O’Rowane falls into a coma. His soul travels to a place where the greatest of the great gather—the honorable Hall of Heroes. There a thousand years pass as Davey undergoes excruciating training under their watchful eyes to become a hero too strong for his own good. Now back to his timeline and his kingdom, he’s wide awake and the enemies hiding in the king’s court better be prepared. The prince they had dismissed is now their biggest threat!


The protagonist was reincarnated as Davey O'Rowane, the First Prince of the tiny Rowane Kingdom.
His mother, Lennie Alishad, was poisoned and killed by Lynesse Bariatta, who became King Krianes' second wife, and Davey was rendered comatose when Lynesses' son, the Second Prince, Carlus, shot him in the back with three arrows.
His soul then arrived at the Hall of Heroes, where he spent a thousand years being trained by legendary dead heroes. Hercules taught him survival skills and he learned a variety of skills from others, including swordsmanship, holy power, necromancy, anatomy and medicine.
After that, his soul returned to his physical body, six years after he'd been shot. His body was weak after being bedridden for so long, so he spent months gathering his strength, before seeking revenge against Lynesse and Carlus.
In addition to his current wife, Queen Lynesse, the King also has two concubines, Anisha and Alice. The children he fathered with Anisha -- twins Baris and Winley -- are friendly with Davey.
You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.

thank you this is it
